# Conditional has_many foreign_key in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working in the website of an AI competition, where you can upload either a pacman or ghosts controller, they are evaluated, and the results are displayed in the site.

I have one table for the controllers, called 'agents':

```
class CreateAgents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :agents do |t|
      t.string :ctype # either 'pacman' or 'ghosts'
      t.references :user, :null => false
      ...
      t.timestamps
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

Each controller belongs to a user, and they can be of two types: 'pacman' or 'ghosts'.

Two controllers are selected (one pacman, one ghost), and they play a game, and the game is stored in the database:

```
class CreateGames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :games do |t|
      t.integer :pacman_agent_id
      t.integer :ghosts_agent_id
      t.integer :score
      t.timestamps
    end
    ... 
  end
end
```

When I want to select let's say the pacman agent of a particular game, I just do a:

```
Game.first.pacman
```

by using a belongs_to with the appropriate foreign_key:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pacman, class_name: 'Agent', foreign_key: 'pacman_agent_id'
  belongs_to :ghosts, class_name: 'Agent', foreign_key: 'ghosts_agent_id'
end
```

However, I can't figure out how to do the opposite, which is to select the games, for a particular agent.

I would like to do something like this:

```
Agent.first.games
```

So that would return the games for that particular controller, independently if its a pacman or ghosts controller.

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work:

```
class Agent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :games, foreign_key: (:ctype == 'pacman' ? 'pacman_agent_id' : 'ghosts_agent_id')
end
```

Any ideas? Maybe my database design is incorrect?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas? Maybe my database design is incorrect?

Yes this is absolutely incorrect! xD

Instead of adding two id fields to one model you should use a polymorphic association which also requieres two fields but one containing a type (Model name) and one containing the id. You will find everything you need here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Its kinda complicated at the first time. Theres also a railscast about this theme (#154).

Comment: S..t, I knew something was wrong with my design. This is just my third week doing Rails, I'll read more about polymorphic associations then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, if you don't wanna use polymorphic association :)

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pacman, class_name: 'Agent', foreign_key: :pacman_agent_id
  belongs_to :ghosts, class_name: 'Agent', foreign_key: :ghosts_agent_id
end


class Agent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :pacman_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: :pacman_agent_id
  has_many :ghost_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: :ghosts_agent_id
end

=> Agent.find_by_ctype('pacman').pacman_games
=> Agent.find_by_ctype('ghosts').ghost_games

=> Game.first.pacman
=> Game.first.ghosts
```